# To add an element to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private boolean adopted;
    private String parent;
    private List<String> children;

    public Person(String Aname) {
        name = Aname;
        children = new ArrayList<String>();
        adopted = false;
    }

    public void adopt(Person person) {
        if (!person.adopted && !person.name.equals(name)
                && children.size() <= 10) {
            person.parent = name;
            // System.out.println(parent);
            // children=person.name;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                children.add(i, person.name);
            }
            // System.out.println(children);
            adopted = true;
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void disown(Person person) {

    }

    public String toString() {
        if (children.size() == 0 && parent == null) {
            return name + " Parent: No parent.  Children: No children ";
        } else if (children.size() == 0) {
            return name + " Parent: " + parent + " Children: No children";
        } else if (parent == null) {
            String list = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                list = children.get(i);
            }
            return name + " Parent: No Parent " + "Children: " + list;
        } else {
            String list = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                list = children.get(i);
            }
            return name + " Parent: " + parent + " Children: " + list;
        }
    }
}
```

In this I am trying to add person.name to arraylist children but I am not able to add. I am initialyzing the list then adding a name to the list.I am using adopt method to add children to the list. Please tell what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You haven't really told us what's wrong. Are you getting compiler error? Not getting expected output? What?

Comment: I am not getting any detials of the children in the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of items in you arraylist "children" is 0.

Look at this part code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    children.add(i, person.name);
}
```

for every object in children you will set the same name.

So you will set the name 0 times. That means there also won't be any output.

I think you need an array with al the persons you create in you main.
Change the adopt code to this:

```
public void adopt(Person person) {
    if (!person.adopted && !person.name.equals(this.name)) {
        person.parent = name;
        children.add(person.name);
        person.adopted = true;
    }
}
```

Make getters for your atributes or make them public like this:

> public String name;

In your main:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[5];
persons[0] = new Person("Dude");
persons[1] = new Person("Dude's child");

persons[0].adopt(persons[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The properties are private, please put setters and getters and then try to access to the getName() property.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that after you create the new ArrayList(); you never assign any value to the list, so when you iterate based on children.size(), you will always iterate from 0 to 0 and never add any children in the next snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            children.add(i, person.name);
        }
```

As per @summerbulb suggestion: `person.name` should be adopted by the current this so you should just do

```
children.add(person.name)
```

Also, at the end of the adopt method, I think you want to mark person (the parameter) as adopted and not this (the person adopting), so you may change

```
person.adopted=true;
```

instead of just `adopted=true;`

Answer (score 1):

The following code is incorrect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    children.add(i, person.name);
}
```

Each time you call `Adopt(person)` you add that child instead of all the children in the list.

Try using:

```
children.add(person.name);
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, the above is correct, but cristobal de Leon's answer is the explanation to what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `toString` method. I am not sure if all children are printed. E.g. look at the case in which parent is not NULL and children.size() > 0

```
String list = null;
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
  list = children.get(i);
}
return name + " Parent: " + parent + " Children: " + list;
```

Here you are iterating over all children, take the name of the last children in the list and return it together with the parents name.

Besides: please check if children can also be of class `Person`

Comment: How do I display the names of all the childrens?